# Scraping coin gecko with pandas report HTTP Error 403

Tags: python, pandas

I have used pd.read_html(url) to **scrape** tables from url before without problems but with [www.coingecko.com](http://www.coingecko.com) I got a HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. Do I really need access permissions or I am doing something wrong?

Code used:

```
url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en?page=1"
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can behave like you are a browser and send request to get the body of the response.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = "https://www.coingecko.com/en?page=1"
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.head()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cute Panda. This worked as I needed

Comment: Your suggestion has been working fine until today. If I run your code now I get a one column and one row dataframe with this '''Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page....'''

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoPalacios I tried running the code today and it worked perfectly. I got 100 rows * 10 columns output