# How to create many data frames and combine them in one big data frame to avoid creating multiple variables

Tags: python, dataframe

I am scraping a HTML and storing data in a pandas dataframe. I need a loop for because the data in the html is in more than one url. My first idea was to create as many data frames as url I have, creating many variables but I have read that this is a bad idea. The solution I have read is to create a dict but I dont see how I can do this with data frames. I just want a final data frame with the information from the first row of the first data frame to the last row of the last dataframe.

This is my code so far

```
# To simulate I am a browser and send request to get the body of the response.
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
# Coingecko containes 100 coins per page
uncomplete_URL = "https://www.coingecko.com/en?page="
for page in  range (1,100): # Because I only want to analise the first 1000 coins
    complete_URL = uncomplete_URL + str(page)
    # To request info and then populate a pandas dataframe
    r = requests.get(complete_URL, headers=header)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    df = pd.concat(df) # EDIT I forgot this line
    tmp_df.head()
```

Most of this code is taking from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609028/scraping-coin-gecko-with-pandas-report-http-error-403)

Comment: I would store dataframes on a list and then do `pd.concat(dfs)` in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final results so far  I have got after applying the suggestion of people who asnwered

```
# To simulate I am a browser and send request to get the body of the response.
header = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
d = pd.DataFrame() # init a dataframe
# Coingecko containes 100 coins per page
uncomplete_URL = "https://www.coingecko.com/en?page="
for page in  range (1,3): # Because I only want to analise the first 1000 coins
    complete_URL = uncomplete_URL + str(page)
    # To request info and then populate a pandas dataframe
    r = requests.get(complete_URL, headers=header)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    tmp_df = pd.concat(dfs)
    d = pd.concat([d, tmp_df]) # concat `tmp_df` with initial dataframe `d`

d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way with `pd.concat`,

```
d = pd.DataFrame() # init a dataframe
for page in  range (1,2): # Because I only want to analise the first 1000 coins
    complete_URL = uncomplete_URL + str(page)
    # To request info and then populate a pandas dataframe
    r = requests.get(complete_URL, headers=header)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    tmp_df_str(page) = pd.concat(dfs)
    tmp_df.head()
    d = pd.concat([d, tmp_df]) # concat `tmp_df` with initial dataframe `d`

print(d)
```

Comment: I am trying to apply your suggestion but I got this error: TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: what is the type of your `dfs`? isn't it dataframe? what is `tmp_df`?

Comment: My bad. I forgot one line of code I will add with a comment.

Comment: ALways Sunny, now after last line I have forgot, your suggestion worked. Many thanks

Comment: I have seen that I only get 100 rows why?

Comment: not sure about that it should all there when you concat

Comment: The problems is in the last line of code (d = pd.concat([d, tmp_df])) doest work. If I introduce a print like that print(df.iloc[[0]]) I get the first row of each data frame but then in the final one I just got 100 rows ???

Comment: can you put a new line inside of your for loop, `print(tmp_df.shape)` and `print(d.shape)`?

Comment: Always Sunny I have added some changes. Your suggestion finally worked. I have added this as an answer but the merit if your. Thanks

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoPalacios glad it helps you sir. best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I will put all the dataframe inside a dictionary since it is way faster and efficient. After finishing the loop, I use pd concat

```
dict_df = {}
for page in  range (1,100): # Because I only want to analise the first 1000 coins
    complete_URL = uncomplete_URL + str(page)
    # To request info and then populate a pandas dataframe
    r = requests.get(complete_URL, headers=header)
    dfs = pd.read_html(r.text)
    dict_df[page] = dfs
final_df = pd.concat(dict_df.values(), ignore_index=True)
```